# IBM worklight 5.0.6 - "The server was unable to process the request from the application"

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, ripple, worklight-console

I've folow [this tutorial](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/02_04_Previewing_your_application_on_BlackBerry_6_and_7.pdf), but when I preview my application on the BlackBerry Ripple Emulator I get the following:

[image]

The error in the Chrome dev tools console:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment to this answer:

Note: due to a defect in Worklight 5.0.6, previewing the Windows Phone 7.5, Windows Phone 8 and BlackBerry 6/7 environments in Worklight Console (or MBS, or Ripple...) - **will fail.**

The environments will function correctly when used in an actual device or simulator, but not when previewing the web resources.

This defect is fixed in Worklight 6.0.

Comment: I'm using worklight 5.0.6, when i've run with android mobile simulator and iphone simulator every thing ok

Comment: Open the Chrome developer tools and refresh the page, what error do you see there? Edit the question.

Comment: i've run every thing ok in Common Resources, android mobile simulator and iphone simulator but can't run on blackberry mobile simulator

Comment: You can use the BlackBerry Simulator instead of Ripple. Ripple only loads the web resources; a simulator would be better if you don't have a device.

Comment: I've folow this [link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/02_04_Previewing_your_application_on_BlackBerry_6_and_7.pdf) and build to .code file to run on blackberry simulator,but it can't conect to server too.although blackberry simulator can conect to internet but can't conect to server worklight

Comment: The defect may extend to the simulator as well, then, in the case of BlackBerry. :/ As said, fixed in the latest Worklight version. Are you  an IBMer, IBM partner or customer?

Comment: i'm a student work about worklight in my thesis of my university

Comment: Ok. Well, there's a bug... fixed in 6.0; why not upgrade? If this answers your question, please mark as Answered... Thanks.